# three ways to create a circular list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, circular-list

I'm interested in circular / infinite lists in Haskell. I read about **let..in** statements and **where** clauses and I get the feeling that they have an important part to play, but I still don't get it.

To be concrete, I've written three versions of code for an infinite list of alternating 0's and 1's. I take it that this is what is meant by a circular list in Haskell.

```
cyclic = let x = 0 : y 
             y = 1 : x
         in x

cyclic' = [0,1] ++ cyclic'

cyclic'' = [0,1] ++ x
    where x = cyclic''
```

The second one seems simplest, shortest and most natural to me, but maybe that's because I'm still not entirely comfortable with let..in and while.

Are all these three lists represented the same way?

Comment: While I'm at it, let me throw in one more version: 'cyclic3 = let x = [0,1] ++ y  y = x in x '

Comment: You could make infinite lists with `Data.List` functions `repeat` and `cycle`

Comment: Fourth option, just `cyclic = 0:1:cyclic`.

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to mention an important distinction:

```
cyclic' = [0,1] ++ cyclic'

cyclic'' = [0,1] ++ x
    where x = cyclic''
```

These two functions **are recursive** in the sense that the definition of the function references itself. But

```
cyclic = let x = 0 : y 
             y = 1 : x
         in x
```

**is not!** It uses `x` internally, which is recursive, but the whole `cyclic` isn't - in its definition there is no reference to itself. This is also why they're different when compiled into the core language.

This has some important practical implications, namely that recursive functions can't be [inlined](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-noinline-pragma), but non-recursive can. This is why you often see definitions like

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

(from the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Function.html#fix) of `Data.Function`) instead of more direct

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

(I'm not really sure why GHC doesn't do this automatically.)

Just for completeness, there are other short ways how to define `cyclic`:

```
-- recursive:
cyclic = 0 : 1 : cyclic
-- non-recursive:
cyclic = let x = 0 : 1 : x in x
cyclic = cycle [0,1]
cyclic = fix ([0,1] ++)
```

---

**Update:** To give an example: Let's define

```
-- The `const` combinator, defined explicitly so that
-- it gets inlined.
k :: a -> b -> a
k x y = x

fix, fix' :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f     = let x = f x in x
fix' f    = f (fix' f)

main = do
    print $ fix (k 1)
    print $ fix' (k 2)
```

So `fix'` is recursive, while `fix` isn't (the definition of `fix` is copied from `Data.Function`). What happens when we use `fix'`? The compiler can't inline it, because after inlining, it would get an expression that contains `fix'` again. Should it inline it the second time? And then the third time? Therefore, *recursive functions are never inlined by design.* On the other hand, `fix` isn't recursive, so `fix (k 1)` gets inlined into `let x = k 1 x in x`. Then the compiler inlines `k`, which results in `let x = 1 in x`, which is replaced simply by `1`.

We can verify the above claim by dumping the compiled code in the core language:

```
$ ghc -ddump-simpl  -dsuppress-all Main.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 24, types: 27, coercions: 0}

Rec {
fix'_reJ
fix'_reJ = \ @ a_c f_aeR -> f_aeR (fix'_reJ f_aeR)
end Rec }

main
main =
  >>
    $fMonadIO
    ($ (print $fShowInteger) (__integer 1))
    ($ (print $fShowInteger)
       (fix'_reJ
          (let {
             x_aeN
             x_aeN = __integer 2 } in
           \ _ -> x_aeN)))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

Comment: The distinction is very important. Functionally you get the same but you should know about what happens inside the machine.

Comment: The explanation is too short. Can you please elaborate? x = f x is recursive. So what do you buy? Inlining of fix? But the "inside" of fix cannot be inlined anyway, because it is recursive.

Comment: oh, cool! x = f x means fix g gets compiled into g calling itself; yet defining fix g = g (fix g) gets compiled into g calling fix, adding indirection on every step of recursion.

Comment: @SassaNF I added an example showing how the non-recursive definition can result in a significant improvement.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I think a more interesting example is important. Replacing recursion with a constant gives insight into just one level of inlining. `k :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int` defined as `k f 0 = 1; k f i = f $ i-1` produces a more interesting code. There we can see that "recursive call" function is computed once as a constant for `x = f x` case, and has to be computed for every step of recursion for `f (fix' f)` case.

Comment: @PetrPudlá , as I see it, in order to take advantage of inlining optimizations which GHC performs under the hood, I should minimize using "recursive functions". From the post above, it seems that "recursive" has a technical meaning (as of yet, unknown to me) which is more restrictive than my naive understanding of the word. 

`cyclic1 = [0,1] ++ cyclic1`
`cyclic2 = let x = [0,1] ++ y; y=x in x`
`cyclic3 = let x = 0 : y ;  y = 1 : x in x`
Apparently, cyclic3 (and I presume also, cyclic2) are not recursive, whereas cyclic1 is. Please try (again) to explain the distinction here.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check this yourself by compiling with the `-fext-core`, which will write a corresponding `.hrc` file for each of your source files, which contains the intermediate "core langauge" for Haskell.  In this case, if we compile this code, we get the rather difficult to read code:

```
%module main:Main

  %rec
  {main:Main.cycliczqzq :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN
                           ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
     base:GHCziBase.zpzp @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
     (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
      (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (0::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh))
      (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
       (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (1::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh))
       (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int)))
     main:Main.cycliczqzq};

  %rec
  {main:Main.cycliczq :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN
                         ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
     base:GHCziBase.zpzp @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
     (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
      (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (0::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh))
      (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int
       (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (1::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh))
       (ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int)))
     main:Main.cycliczq};
  arot :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
    ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (0::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh);
  a1rou :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
    ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Izh (1::ghczmprim:GHCziPrim.Intzh);

  %rec
  {main:Main.cyclic :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN
                       ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
     ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int arot yrov;
   yrov :: ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZMZN ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int =
     ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.ZC @ ghczmprim:GHCziTypes.Int a1rou
     main:Main.cyclic};
```

If we "clean up" this a bit and remove some of the `ghczmprim`s and whatnot, we get

```
{cycliczqzq :: ZMZN Int = zpzp @ Int (ZC @ Int (Izh (0 :: Intzh)) (ZC @ Int (Izh (1 :: Intzh)) (ZMZN @ Int))) cycliczqzq};

{cycliczq :: ZMZN Int = zpzp @ Int (ZC @ Int (Izh (0 :: Intzh)) (ZC @ Int (Izh (1 :: Intzh)) (ZMZN @ Int))) cycliczq};

arot :: Int = Izh (0 :: Intzh);
a1rou :: Int = Izh (1 :: Intzh);

{cyclic :: ZMZN Int = ZC @ Int arot yrov;
 yrov :: ZMZN Int = ZC @ Int a1rou cyclic};
```

In which we can pretty easily tell that `cycliczqzq` and `cycliczq` have the exact same definition, and we can tell that they correlate to `cyclic''` and `cyclic'` respectively.  For `cyclic`, we can tell that it gets defined in a different manner.

**EDIT:**

To add the fourth definition

```hs
cyclic4 :: [Int]
cyclic4 =
    let xx = [1, 0] ++ yy
        yy = xx
    in xx
```

And I also renamed them all to be `cyclic1` through `cyclic4` for better readability.  The output of `-fext-core` with all the garbage removed is

```
{cyclic4 :: ZMZN Int = zpzp @ Int (ZC @ Int (Izh (1::Intzh)) (ZC @ Int (Izh (0::Intzh)) (ZMZN @ Int))) cyclic4};
{cyclic3 :: ZMZN Int = zpzp @ Int (ZC @ Int (Izh (0::Intzh)) (ZC @ Int (Izh (1::Intzh)) (ZMZN @ Int))) cyclic3};
{cyclic2 :: ZMZN Int = zpzp @ Int (ZC @ Int (Izh (0::Intzh)) (ZC @ Int (Izh (1::Intzh)) (ZMZN @ Int))) cyclic2};

aroR :: Int = Izh (0::Intzh);
a1roS :: Int = Izh (1::Intzh);
{cyclic1 :: ZMZN Int = ZC @ Int aroR yroT;
 yroT :: ZMZN Int = ZC @ Int a1roS cyclic1};
```

So we can see that the last three definitions actually get turned into the same byte code.

Also, this was all compiled without optimizations on, since that made it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @PetrPudlak example gives further insight:

```
fix f = let x = f x in x

fix' f = f (fix' f)

k :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
k f 0 = 1
k f i = f $ i-1

main = do
         print $ fix k 10
         print $ fix' k 10
```

Compile:

```
ghc -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all c.hs

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size = 59

k_ra0
k_ra0 =
  \ f_aa4 ds_dru ->
    case ds_dru of wild_X6 { I# ds1_drv ->
    case ds1_drv of _ {
      __DEFAULT -> $ f_aa4 (- $fNumInt wild_X6 (I# 1));
      0 -> I# 1
    }
    }

main
main =
  >>
    $fMonadIO
    ($ (print $fShowInt)
       (letrec {
          x_ah6
          x_ah6 = k_ra0 x_ah6; } in
        x_ah6 (I# 10)))
    ($ (print $fShowInt)
       (letrec {
          fix'_ah0
          fix'_ah0 = \ f_aa3 -> f_aa3 (fix'_ah0 f_aa3); } in
        fix'_ah0 k_ra0 (I# 10)))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

Here it is clear that the first case, `fix`, gets to construct a constant once, which gets reused in recursion, but the second case, `fix'`, has to construct a new stub on every step of recursion.